# How to get a UTC clock widget on Awesome WM?

Tags: awesome, clock

Is there a way to get a second clock widget in Awesome WM displaying UTC datetime, without having to change my timezone? As a developer UTC is *the* reference timezone, so it's really useful to be able to glance at to determine facts about a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added time on my calendar and display Paris or Melbourne time [my calendar widget](https://github.com/utix/dotfiles/blob/master/config/awesome/calendar2.lua) You can check this to update your widget.

The main magic is here:

```
    local f = io_m.popen("TZ='"..locale.."' date +%H:%M") 
    local s = f:read('*a') 
    local header = os.date("%B %Y  ",os.time{year=year,month=month,day=1})..s
```

Quick how to use:
Create a widget:

```
mytextclock = awful.widget.textclock()
require('calendar2')
calendar2.addCalendarToWidget(mytextclock, io, "<span color=\"yellow\"><b>%s</b></span>")
```

Then

put your widget into your wibox

```
-- Create the wibox
mywibox = {}
for s = 1, screen.count() do

    mywibox[s] = awful.wibox({ position = "top", screen = s })

    mywibox[s].widgets = {
            {
                mylauncher,
                mytaglist[s],
                mypromptbox[s],
                ["layout"] = awful.widget.layout.horizontal.leftright
            },
            mylayoutbox[s],
            mytextclock,
            ["layout"] = awful.widget.layout.horizontal.rightleft
        }
```

Comment: @l0b0 I have added some main line to use it

Answer (score 2):

I actually ended up with [this solution](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/tilde/commit/d7cf3b7cea2015031bfe5d8da84d0d8669870020):

```
clock_format = "%a %Y-%m-%d %H:%M %Z"
utc_textclock = wibox.widget.textclock(" " .. clock_format, nil, "Z")
local_textclock = wibox.widget.textclock(" — " .. clock_format .. " ")
```